# Why does my program crash when textfields are left blank?

Tags: java, user-interface, crash, jtextfield

I have this program for school, and it works fine when you fill out all of the text fields. But, if you leave anything blank on the fields, the entire program will crash. Here is my code:

```
 /** Kyle N Welch
  * Sept 29th, 2017
  * This program will calculate the expanses of a business
  * man/woman on a business trip using the GUI
  * */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

//Class name declaration
public class KNW_TravelExpenses extends JFrame
{
  private JPanel travelInfoPanel;
  private JPanel buttonPanel;

  // Labels
  private JLabel numDaysOnTripLabel;
  private JLabel amountAirfairLabel;
  private JLabel amountCarRentalLabel;
  private JLabel milesDrivenLabel;
  private JLabel parkingFeesLabel;
  private JLabel taxiFeesLabel;
  private JLabel confRegLabel;
  private JLabel lodgingChargesPerNightLabel;

  // Text Fields
  private JTextField numDaysOnTripTextField;
  private JTextField amountAirfairTextField;
  private JTextField amountCarRentalTextField;
  private JTextField milesDrivenTextField;
  private JTextField parkingFeesTextField;
  private JTextField taxiFeesTextField;
  private JTextField confRegTextField;
  private JTextField lodgingChargesPerNightTextField;

  // Buttons
  private JButton resetButton;
  private JButton calcButton;

  // Meals amount reimbursed by company per day.
  private double mealsAmount = 37.00;

  // Parking Fees amount reimbursed by company per day.
  private double parkingFeesReimbursed = 10.00;

  // Taxi Charges amount reimbursed by company per day.
  private double taxiChargesReimbursed = 20.00;

  // Lodging Charges amount reimbursed by company per day.
  private double lodgingChargesReimbursed = 95.00;

  // Private Vehicle per miles reimbursment rate.
  private double prVechiclePerMileReimbursed = 0.27;

  // Constructor
  public KNW_TravelExpenses( )
  {
    //set the title.
    super("TRAVEL EXPENSES");
    // Set the main window
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    // Specify an action for the close button.
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    // Create a BorderLayout manager for the content pane.
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    // Build the TravelInfo and Buttons panels
    buildTravelInfoPanel();
    buildButtonPanel();
    // Add the panels to the frame's content pane
    add(travelInfoPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    // Pack the contents of the window and display it.
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
  }
  // The buildTravelInfoPanel method adds the labels
  //and text fiels to the TravelInfo panel.
  private void buildTravelInfoPanel()
  {
    // Create the labels for TravelInfo fields
    numDaysOnTripLabel = new JLabel("Number of days on trip: ");
    amountAirfairLabel = new JLabel("Amount of airfair: ");
    amountCarRentalLabel = new JLabel("Amount of car rental fees: ");
    milesDrivenLabel = new JLabel("Number of Miles driven: ");
    parkingFeesLabel = new JLabel("Amount of Parking fees: ");
    taxiFeesLabel = new JLabel("Amount of Tax charges: ");
    confRegLabel = new JLabel("Conference or Seminar registration fees: ");
    lodgingChargesPerNightLabel = new JLabel("Lodging charges per night: ");
    // Create the text boxes for TravelInfo user input
    numDaysOnTripTextField = new JTextField(3);
    amountAirfairTextField = new JTextField(8);
    amountCarRentalTextField = new JTextField(8);
    milesDrivenTextField = new JTextField(4);
    parkingFeesTextField = new JTextField(6);
    taxiFeesTextField = new JTextField(6);
    confRegTextField = new JTextField(8);
    lodgingChargesPerNightTextField = new JTextField(6);
    // Create a panel to hold labels and text fields.
    travelInfoPanel = new JPanel();
    // Create GridLayout manager
    travelInfoPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 2));
    // Add the labels and text fields to this panel.
    travelInfoPanel.add(numDaysOnTripLabel);
    travelInfoPanel.add(numDaysOnTripTextField);
    travelInfoPanel.add(amountAirfairLabel);
    travelInfoPanel.add(amountAirfairTextField);
    travelInfoPanel.add(amountCarRentalLabel);
    travelInfoPanel.add(amountCarRentalTextField);
    travelInfoPanel.add(milesDrivenLabel);
    travelInfoPanel.add(milesDrivenTextField);
    travelInfoPanel.add(parkingFeesLabel);
    travelInfoPanel.add(parkingFeesTextField);
    travelInfoPanel.add(taxiFeesLabel);
    travelInfoPanel.add(taxiFeesTextField);
    travelInfoPanel.add(confRegLabel);
    travelInfoPanel.add(confRegTextField);
    travelInfoPanel.add(lodgingChargesPerNightLabel);
    travelInfoPanel.add(lodgingChargesPerNightTextField);
    // Add an empty border around the panel for spacing.
    travelInfoPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 1, 10));
  }

  /*** The buildButtonPanel method creates and adds the Reset and Calculate
    * buttons to the TravelExpense panel as its own panel.
    */
  private void buildButtonPanel()
  {
    // Create the calcButton.
    calcButton = new JButton("CALCULATE");

    // Register an event listener
    calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());

    //Create the resetButton.
    resetButton = new JButton("RESET");

    // Create the Buttons panels.
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();

    buttonPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

    buttonPanel.add(resetButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
    buttonPanel.add(calcButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //Add an empty border around the panel for spacing.
    buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 10, 10, 10));
  }

  /** Private inner class that handles the event when the user clicks
    * the Calculate button .
    */
  private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
    // Declare variables
    String input;
    int days;
    double air;
    double carRental;
    double miles;
    double parking;
    double taxi;
    double confReg;
    double lodging;
    double mealsAmount;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      //Declare variables
      double actualExpenses;
      double milesExpenses;
      double allowableExpenses;
      double excessAir;
      double excessCarRental;
      double excessParking;
      double excessTaxi;
      double excessLodging;
      double excessAmountTotal;
      double amountSaved=0;
      double paidBackAmount=0;

      //Create a DecimalFormat object to format the totals as dollar amounts.
      DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00");

      //Get Input Data the user entered in the text fields.
      days = Integer.parseInt(numDaysOnTripTextField.getText());
      air = Double.parseDouble(amountAirfairTextField.getText());
      carRental = Double.parseDouble(amountCarRentalTextField.getText());
      miles = Double.parseDouble(milesDrivenTextField.getText());
      parking = Double.parseDouble(parkingFeesTextField.getText());
      taxi = Double.parseDouble(taxiFeesTextField.getText());
      confReg = Double.parseDouble(confRegTextField.getText());
      lodging = Double.parseDouble(lodgingChargesPerNightTextField.getText());

      //Determine actualExpenses method.
      milesExpenses = miles * prVechiclePerMileReimbursed;
      actualExpenses = (carRental + parking + taxi + lodging +mealsAmount)
        *days+air+milesExpenses+ confReg ;

      // Calculate the allowableExpenses.
      allowableExpenses=(mealsAmount+parkingFeesReimbursed+taxiChargesReimbursed+lodgingChargesReimbursed)
        *days+milesExpenses+air+confReg;

      // Calculate the paidBackAmount.
      if(actualExpenses>allowableExpenses)
        paidBackAmount=actualExpenses-allowableExpenses;
      else
        amountSaved=allowableExpenses-actualExpenses;

      // Display the Totals message box.
      if(paidBackAmount>0)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total expenses: "
                                        + dollar.format(actualExpenses) +"\n" +"Allowable expenses: "
                                        + dollar.format(allowableExpenses)+"\n" +"\n" + "Amount to be paid back: "
                                        +dollar.format(paidBackAmount));
      else if(amountSaved>0)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total expenses: " + dollar.format(actualExpenses)
                                        +"\n" +"Allowable expenses: " + dollar.format(allowableExpenses)+"\n" +
                                      "\n" + "Amount Saved: "+dollar.format(amountSaved));
      else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total expenses: " + dollar.format(actualExpenses)
                                        +"\n" +"Allowable expenses: " + dollar.format(allowableExpenses)+"\n" );
    }
  }

  /*** Private inner class that handles the event when the user clicks
    * the RESET button .
    */
  private class ResetButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      numDaysOnTripTextField.setText(" ");
      amountAirfairTextField.setText(" ");
      amountCarRentalTextField.setText(" ");
      milesDrivenTextField.setText(" ");
      parkingFeesTextField.setText(" ");
      taxiFeesTextField.setText(" ");
      confRegTextField.setText(" ");
      lodgingChargesPerNightTextField.setText(" ");
    }
  }
// The main method
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new TravelExpenses();
  }
}
```

Anything that could cause the GUI program to crash when the fields are left blank. There has to be something and I am clearly missing it. Any help would be appreciated if you could just point it out to me and tell me how it could be fixed?

Comment: Please take the time to edit your code down to a [mcve].

Comment: Gimme the stack trace

Comment: @a_river_in_canada

Comment: Define "crash".  How specifically does it fail?  What is the exception or error?  When you step through in a debugger, where specifically does it happen?

Comment: try casting " " to integer/double..you will get what you need

Answer (score 1):

Try try-catch when you use `parseInt` because its raise `FormatException`(trying to `parseInt` from `null` string can end with crash).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the error happens because you try to treat an empty string as a number. Is the program supposed to work with missing data? If yes, you have to amend your calculation, either to treat blanks as zeros or in some other way.

The important lesson is to look at stack trace. Java will tell you exactly what and where went wrong. As others have said, either reduce your program to something minimal so we don't have to guess, or provide a stack trace.